# How to bring up wifi interface automatically on Focal?

Tags: boot, wireless, 20.04, interface

Using Ubuntu Focal..... I am not able to get the wifi interface to come up automatically on each boot. I don't need dhcpcd.... I just need the wifi device up so I can run wpa_supplicant.

I modified `/etc/network/interfaces` but to no success:

```
% cat /etc/network/interfaces 
auto wlp58s0
iface wlp58s0 inet
```

Comment: Ubuntu Server or Ubuntu Desktop? Also, /etc/network/interfaces was deprecated years ago in favor of [Netplan](http://netplan.io/examples).

Comment: This is Ubuntu server

Comment: Then use that Netplan link. It shows you how to setup your network using Netplan YAML. The first section on that page shows you how to apply the changes and bring up your interfaces.

Comment: And after you set up netplan, please revert your changes to /etc/network/interfaces.